# Validate JSON Object using Sequelize model validiation before creation

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is there a way to validate an incoming JSON Object using Sequelize Model validation without creating an object?
Basically check that the Object is legit to do some further modification before its inserted into the database?
For example:

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({
     ...
}, { sequelize });

app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
      var preproc=req.body
      if(User.validate(preproc){
         if(preproc.dob.month=12 && preproc.dob.day=24){
              preproc.description=preproc.description+" btw I was born on Christmas";
         }
         const user = await User.create(preproc);
         ...
      }
      ...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a validate method. But you can only call on instance of Model.

```js
let instance = new User(req.body);
// alternate : let instance = User.build(req.body);
instance.validate();
```

You can look into package Joi if you want more better validation of json.